# read from file to array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

i wanna read from file to array of unsigned char in RAD studio 2010, i have an example,but i need to read to array size of file. Sorry my english

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ChooseFileClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  TOpenDialog *od = new TOpenDialog(this);
  if (od->Execute()) {
    TFileStream *fs = new TFileStream(od->FileName,fmOpenRead);
    fs->Position = soFromBeginning;
    TMemo *m = new TMemo(this);
    m->Parent = this;
    m->Lines->LoadFromStream(fs);
    delete fs;
    fs = NULL;
  }
  delete od;
  od = NULL;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what is the problem with this code. – Falls du Deutsch sprichst (vermute ich anhand deines Namens einfach mal): es wäre schon nötig dass du ein bischen das Problem beschreibst. Es wird hier sicherlich nicht gern gesehen, aber auch wenn du nicht auf englisch schreibst nützt es was.

Comment: Nur wenn Sie das uebersetzen :) @leftaroundabout

Comment: here i write file to TMemo, but i wanna to write it to array

Comment: I see. Do you want to read the entire file to one single array, or just line-by-line? [Ganze Datei in ein Array, oder Zeile für Zeile?]

Comment: yes, the entire file(i don't speak German)

Comment: Sorry... ok, so you already have the array allocated, or do you need one created for you with the correct size?

Comment: I can't understand why all these RAD tools feel that in addition to providing GUI objects (which is useful), they have to provide their own file-handling classes, serial ports, etc., etc. which are just as complicated as the standard ones, buggy, and don't return as detailed error codes.  In this case, the sooner you ditch `TFileStream` the better.  It would also be good to ditch the Java-esque use of dynamic memory allocation for local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure of your exact intent, I can tell you this: don't use a raw array!

In C++, we have the `vector` type. A vector is very similar to an array, but you can keep adding elements to it. If it gets full, it makes itself bigger. (In actual fact, a vector is simply a wrapper for an array. When it is filled up, it creates a larger array, copies the element to the new array, and then discards the original array).

When using `vector`, you're code follows this style:

```
#include <vector> // so we can actually use vectors

... // program code here

// here's a basic loop which fills a vectors with the numbers 1 to 99.
std::vector<unsigned char> myVec;
while( there_is_stuff_to_read )
{
    myVec.push_back(get_next_element());
}
```

Of course, the loop would involve whatever file reading classes you use. The key is the `push_back` method which adds elements to the vector.

If other portions of your code rely specifically on using an array of unsigned char, then you can fill the vector, and the use this line of code as necessary:

```
unsigned char * arr = &myVec[0];
```

Then you can use `arr` as your usual unsigned char array. Just make sure that you don't hang on this pointer after adding more elements to the vector. It isn't guaranteed to remain a valid pointer to the start of the vector's internal array (since the vector reallocates its internal array).

The previous line of code doesn't create a whole new array. If you want a genuine copy of the internal contents of the vector, you can use something like:

```
unsigned char * arr = new unsigned char[myVec.size()];
std::copy(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), arr);
```

Just make sure you include the standard <algorithm> header.